# upload files from ec2 to s3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm building a php application trying to upload files ec2 to s3. The files don't get uploaded to s3 and I don't get any error messages. I have added a role in the bucket policy with administration access ec2 full access s3 full access

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::601825519382:user/admin-infosecure",
                    "arn:aws:iam::601825519382:role/@forInfosecure"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::infosecure.buck"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Amazon S3 policy is granting permissions **on the bucket** (good for things like `ListBucket`), but not ***within* the bucket** (for things like `GetObject`).

Replace your `Resource` with this:

```
"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::infosecure.buck", "arn:aws:s3:::infosecure.buck/*"]
```

If that doesn't work, it might be a different part of your policy that's having problems. **Debug** it by granting permission to a principal of `*` and a resource of `*`, confirm it works, then successively add restrictions until you run into a problem (eg syntax of an ARN).